# Web services using java

Tags: xml, web-services

I have created simple web services to convert temperature.
i have deployed it on tomcat under webserivces folder but when i am trying to access it using url "http://localhost:8080/YoutubeExample/ConverterService" its giving me an error shown below

"HTTP Status 404 - /YoutubeExample/Converter type Status report
message /YoutubeExample/Converter
description The requested resource is not available."

Can you please let me know the reason for the same.

Comment: url is "http://localhost:8080/YoutubeExample/Converter".

Comment: what have you used to develop your web service? cxf ? axis2 ? or any other web service runtime or code.